# Where should I add a configuration file for React Component Library

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am writing a React component library that I'd like to publish to npm.

There are a couple configurations that are required to use the library.

Should I just suggest that the user create a .env file or should I use the context API to pass the data down to the application or is there a completely separate option that I'm not thinking about?

Right now I just have a file called RegistrationDetails.js

```
  domain: '', // Example: images.mysite.com
  ssl: true, // HTTPS or HTTP
};

export default RegistrationDetails;
```

And I import this back into the main component. I don't want the user to have to go into the node_module to update this config file.

This is how I'm using the configuration.

```
  const { domain } = RegistrationDetails;
  const secure = RegistrationDetails.ssl ? 'https://' : 'http://';
  const imgSrc = buildUrl(src, options);

  const renderUrl = secure + domain + imgSrc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'd suggest you to have a `.env` file.**

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env),

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!
>
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

Benifit of having `.env` file is, you don't have to import anything. Variables in `.env` file are available to your app even in `HTML` file.

Variables in `.env` file are `CONSTANTS`, so the naming convention is `UPPERCASE`.

**Create a `.env` file in the root of your project's directory,**

You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. The `create-react-app` tool uses `REACT_APP_` to identify these variables.

```
REACT_APP_DOMAIN = //Domain_Name 
REACT_APP_SSL = true
```

These environment variables will be defined for you on `process.env`. For example, having an environment variable named `REACT_APP_SSL` will be exposed in your JS as `process.env.REACT_APP_SSL`.

```
const secure = process.env.REACT_APP_SSL ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

You can also access the environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_` in the `public/index.html`

```
<title>%REACT_APP_DOMAIN%</title>
```

**Finally,** add the `.env` file to your `.gitignore` file so that `Git` ignores it and it never pushed on `GitHub`.

> Note: You need to restart the development server after changing `.env` files.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of why I should be using the .env file. I think that is the approach I'm going to go with.